# Need database selection advise

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I know this is considered a bad question since there is no correct answer, but I need to decide on a database for embedded linux (DaVinci 368 based) hardware and I've never had to produce a design with a database before. Each record will probably contain less than 1000 images with associated alpha-numeric data and the mass storage will be some kind of flash drive. Only one user needs access to the data at a time. MySQL claims to be "The world's most popular open source database" but SQLite claims to be "the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world." Perhaps there is another that is also the best in the world? Which is easiest to use for a database newbie? Should I just flip a coin? Does it really matter which one I pick? Do I even need to use a database software package or should I roll my own? I won't need bells and whistles like sorting, but I'll probably need to delete the oldest records to make room for new ones if the storage fills up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont have any experience with databases on embedded systems but I think you should go with SQLite. I say this because it realy is LITE and should consume less resources. As you said you dont need bells&whistles so you wont miss any feature not present in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I would always prefer MYSQL because of :

It is very famous.

It is very flexible.

It is very extensible. ie. many of the programming languages allow you to connect with this database.

It is open - sourced. ie. So you can edit the code and enter your own code.

The tutorials for learning it are very easily available.

It also uses less resources.